Are countable sequences of strictly monotone increasing values with a maximum finite?
I have a strictly increasing sequence of values $\{a_i\}$, with $a_i \in \mathbb{R}^+$, so $a_i < a_{i+1}$, that are bounded above by a value $a$ which is actually attained, i.e. $a_i \in (0,a]$.  Does this imply that the sequence is finite, or is there some way that we can have the infinite sequence then with $a$ somehow "on top?"  (I think the answer is obviously that the sequence must be finite but I am confusing myself).

"Sequence" means the index set is either finite or $\omega$ (which makes your added emphasis on "countable" a bit odd), so the only way it has a last element is if it's finite.  You could stick a number at the end by considering $\omega+1$ as your index set, but then you're abusing the language.

@BrianMoehring Thank you, and so to be clear if we have $a_i < a_{i+1}$ for all $i$ and at some $i$ we have $a_i = a$, then this implies the sequence is finite?

Please do not answer in the comments, @TheoBendit.

@Shaun Could you please answer my meta question on this topic? I would find it helpful to hear your perspective.

Let $n$ be a number such that $a_n=a$, which exists because of your hypothesis. If you could define $a_{n+1}$ it would have to satisfy $a\geq a_{n+1}$ since $a$ is an upper bound, and satisfy $a_{n+1}>a_n$ since it's strictly increasing. Therefore, you would have
$$a\geq a_{n+1}>a_n=a$$
Which implies $a>a$ which is of course a contradiction. Therefore the sequence must be finite
